# Center div vertically depending on content

Tags: html, css

Hello I got a question regarding centering a div vertically. Let me explain it by some code. I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
          <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              </p>
      </div>
      <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a class="button" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- LARGE CONTENT -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
          <p>
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi scelerisque porta cursus. Fusce ut nisi eget enim vestibulum pulvinar ac vehicula purus
              </p>
      </div>
      <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a class="button" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

If you look at my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wvd9pddg/) you will see that the yellow div is floating and that is exactly what I want.

What I want to achieve is the following setup:
[image]

I  tried several things like setting the padding / margin as a perceptual number but that did not work. Is it even possible with only CSS?

Comment: The first rule about vertical alignment is "Don't use `float`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods, none of which use `float`. Here's a couple....

**Inline-block / vertical-align**

```css
body{background-color:#fff;}
.container{
  width:555px;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.content{
  background-color:red;
 width:89%;
    display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
  color:#fff;
}
.button_wrapper{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-left: -.25em;
}
.button{
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-48.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 display:block;
 width:48px;
 height:48px; 
 background-position:center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
          <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a class="button" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- LARGE CONTENT -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
          <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi scelerisque porta cursus. Fusce ut nisi eget enim vestibulum pulvinar ac vehicula purus
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a class="button" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
body{background-color:#fff;}
.container{
  width:555px;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.content{
  background-color:red;
 width:89%;
  color:#fff;
}
.button_wrapper{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 10%;
}
.button{
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-48.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 display:block;
 width:48px;
 height:48px; 
 background-position:center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
          <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a class="button" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- LARGE CONTENT -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
          <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi scelerisque porta cursus. Fusce ut nisi eget enim vestibulum pulvinar ac vehicula purus
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="button_wrapper">
          <a class="button" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS Tables**

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
  width: 555px;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  background-color: red;
  width: 89%;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
}
.button_wrapper {
  width: 10%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-48.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button_wrapper">
      <a class="button" href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- LARGE CONTENT -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi scelerisque porta cursus. Fusce ut nisi eget enim vestibulum pulvinar ac vehicula purus
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button_wrapper">
      <a class="button" href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your  solutions! I will mark this as answer due to the fact of the given possibilities. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Change some css property

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.button_wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 10%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wvd9pddg/2/